# Break variable to dynamic variables

Tags: bash, split, dynamic-variables

The script accepts input as binary of various character length.

For example input can be 00011010 or 001101001101101110111011 (up to 9 sets of 8bits)
I have managed to split them per 8 bit.

`input_space=$(echo "$input" | sed 's/.\{8\}/& /g')`

How can every 8bit set can be stored as a separate dynamic variable?

i.e.  var1=00110100 var2=11011011 var3=10111011

Comment: Since you are using bash: Why do you want separate variables, and don't use an array? Separate variables would make sense, if you need to inherit them to you child processes, but you don't write anything about _exporting_ the variables in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the 8-bit sets in an array and then access them dynamically.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

input="001101001101101110111011"

input_space=($(echo "$input" | sed 's/.\{8\}/& /g'))

for i in "${!input_space[@]}"; do
    var_name="var$(($i+1))"
    declare "$var_name=${input_space[$i]}"
    echo "$var_name=${!var_name}"
done
```

The above script:

1. Splits the input into 8-bit sets,
2. Stores them in the `input_space` array, and then
3. Iterates over the array to create dynamic variables (var1, var2, var3, etc.) using the `declare` command. The `${!var_name}` notation is used to indirectly reference the value of the dynamic variable. **[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)**

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: While that will work for the OPs specific input, the way `input_space` is being populated exposes the `sed` output to the shell for globbing and filename expansion so if `input` could contain any globbing metachars then YMMV on the result depending on your environment settings, contents of the directory you run it form, etc. To safely populate a variable with the contents of command output use `readarray` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a bunch of separate variables with numeric suffixes 1 to 3, use an array with numeric indices 1 to 3, e.g.:

```
$ input='001101001101101110111011'
$ readarray -t var <<<"${input//????????/$'\n'&}"
```

```
$ echo "${var[1]}"
00110100
$ echo "${var[2]}"
11011011
$ echo "${var[3]}"
10111011
```

You could use:

```
"${input//?$(printf '?%.0s' {1..7})/$'\n'&}"
```

instead of hard-coding 8 `?`s but. while the `printf '<string>%.0s' {1..<N>}` idiom can be useful for generating N+1 repeating strings in other contexts, it's unnecessarily complicated for this case.

As pointed out by [@pjh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4154375/pjh) in a comment, bash pattern replacement using `&` depends on the `patsub_replacement` [shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-shopt) option which was introduced with Bash 5.2, released in September 2022. If you don't have that available you can always use some versions of sed:

```
readarray -t var < <(sed 's/.\{8\}/\n&/g' <<<"$input")
```

or any awk:

```
readarray -t var < <(awk '{gsub(/.{8}/,"\n&")}1' <<<"$input")
```

Either of the above scripts will also populate an empty `var[0]`, just don't use it and use indices starting at `1` as indicated in your question.

Comment: Note that the Bash pattern replacement using `&` depends on the `patsub_replacement` [shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-shopt) option.  That was introduced with Bash 5.2, which was released in September 2022.